# Understanding Dictionary and Dictionary construct

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm just started into the python learning and trying to understand the different construct of dictionary while going through dictionary reading i know it has key and Values format but i have few doubts to understand.

I have Below two dictionary called `d1` and `d2`

```
>>> d1
{'A': 'one', 'B': 'two', 'C': 'three'}
>>> type(d1)
<class 'dict'>
```

In the above sample i see proper dictionary key and value format and while looking at type it says `class dict`

```
>>> d2
{'A': ['B', 'C']}
>>> type(d2)
<class 'dict'>
```

While the above sample i see dictionary key is okay but values are in list format and while looking at type it also says `class dict`

So, How could i process the `d2` into a proper dictionary format `key and value`. saying that i want to process `d2` so it looks like as `d1` then how could that be achieved.

Apologies if something i could not make clear.

Comment: They are both "proper" dictionaries. The type of a dictionary variable tells you nothing about the type of the values. If you'd like to see what the type of the values are, simply do something like `type(next(iter(d2.values())))` (or just index the dictionary with a key that you know). What do you want to get as output? I don't understand at all what you're asking to do.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, i tried that it does not work and says `TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not an iterator`

Comment: Yes, I edited the comment as I realized I left out part of it.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, thnx for edit, i have edited my question just to make it more claer as i could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python Dictionary are an unordered set of key: value pairs.

Keys are unique within a dictionary while values may not be. The values of a dictionary can be of **any type**, but the keys must be of an immutable data type such as strings, numbers, or tuples.

so you can store any type of object in value.

in first example you are storing string in value.
In second example you are storing list in value.

you can access the key value pair using below code.

```
d1 = {'A': 'one', 'B': 'two', 'C': 'three'}
d2 = {'A' : ['B', 'C'], 'D':['E','F']}

for k,v in d1.items():
    print("key = {} value = {}".format(k,v))


for k,v in d2.items():
    print("key = {} value = {}".format(k,v))
```

Output:

```
key = A value = one
key = B value = two
key = C value = three
key = A value = ['B', 'C']
key = D value = ['E', 'F']
```

Comment: Sach, thnx for your answer , can i get the d2 as `{'A': 'B', 'A': 'C'}`

Comment: No, as I mentioned the key should be unique within dictionary so you can not have two value associated with same key.

Comment: But it can be converted reverse way like `{Val:key for key, Value in d2.items() for Val  in Value}` just i see

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, you can just use [`.items() function`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) over the `d2` dictionary as follows:

```
>>> for key, value in d2.items():
...     print(f"{key} : {value}")
```

Try using the [n2w](https://github.com/collin5/python-n2w) python library to convert the number to words and flatten the dictionary to get the desired output.